# How to increase shm size of a kubernetes container (--shm-size equivalent of docker)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

By default docker uses a shm size of 64m if not specified, but that can be increased in docker using --shm-size=256m

How should I increase shm size of a kuberenetes container or use --shm-size of docker in kuberenetes.

Comment: Look up "SizeMemoryBackedVolumes"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in a kubernetes pod. See this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28272)

There is a [workaround from openshift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/shared_memory.html) mentioned in the comments, but it may not be ideal

EDIT: at the time this question was asked, this was not possible. It now is, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47921100/645002 for the correct answer

Comment: Can I set the default shm size on the kubelet node? I did not find any relevant parameters in Kubelet or dockerd.

Comment: It IS possible, please see answers bellow

Answer (score 65):

I originally bumped into this post coming from google and went through the whole kubernetes issue and openshift workaround. Only to find the much simpler solution listed [on another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46434614/1165797) later.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Very infuriating that we greeted with an accepted answer that says "IMPOSSIBLE"

Answer (score 26):

added below line in deployment.yaml and container came up for me which was failing-
basically Mounting an emptyDir to /dev/shm and setting the medium to Memory

```
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: solace-service
         image: solace-pubsub-standard:latest
         volumeMounts:
           - mountPath: /dev/shm
             name: dshm
         ports:
           - containerPort: 8080
     volumes:
       - name: dshm
         emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
```

Comment: it should be without asterisks (medium: Memory)

Comment: done..i guess it was formatted for some reason

Comment: You can usually also add `sizeLimit: 1Gi` to the `emptyDir:` to set a fixed size. By default I think it it gets 50% as a limit, but there is a beta feature gate that allows you to specify your own limit.

Comment: @GregBray sent you a linked in request.pls accept