# Define size for /dev/shm on container engine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I'm running Chrome with xvfb on Debian 8. It works until I open a tab and try to load content. The process dies silently...

Fortunately, I have gotten it to run smoothly on my local docker using `docker run --shm-size=1G`.

There is [a known bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853) that causes it to crash when /dev/shm is too small.

I am deploying to Container engine, and inspecting the OS specs. The host OS has a solid 7G mounted to /dev/shm, but the actual container is only allocated 64M. Chrome crashes.

How can I set the size of /dev/shm when using kubectl to deploy to container engine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase shm size of a kubernetes container (--shm-size equivalent of docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373463/how-to-increase-shm-size-of-a-kubernetes-container-shm-size-equivalent-of-doc)

Comment: I just posted a similar question, relating to app engine flexible instead of container engine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414587/how-to-change-the-size-of-dev-shm-in-app-engine-flexible

Comment: Look up "SizeMemoryBackedVolumes"

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Mounting an `emptyDir` to /dev/shm and setting the medium to `Memory` did the trick!

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: dshm
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/project/image
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /dev/shm
        name: dshm
```

Comment: I'm having a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401805/howto-set-docker-swarm-runtime-volume-size-dev-shm), but with docker swarm. I don't see `spec:` or `containers:` entries in the docker-compose [reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). How does this map to the [volumes spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)?

Comment: I recommend posting a new question that is specific to docker swarm

Comment: Thank you!!! One truly cannot configure options to the docker launch in the kube config (and the devs are consistently obtuse about not understanding the need for this). Your config has our docker-ized selenium test no longer randomly crashing.

Comment: but where to constrains the size of emptyDir?

Comment: Size limit is being worked on here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/63641

Comment: Be aware that sizeLimit on the emptyDir will result in pod evictions if the limit is exceeded. This is much worse behavior than memory-hungry apps crashing.

Comment: It worked for me on a Kubernetes (AWS EKS) cluster. Thanks SO MUCH

Comment: Setting the size should be possible now via https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/94444

Comment: To specify a size limit:

```yaml
- name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
            sizeLimit: 1Gi
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly well! My configuration is Jenkins and an agent with Robot Framework on an Openshift cluster (in case it would of some help for someone else)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the resource limit which was causing the issue.
It was set to 128 MB earlier then I changed it to 1 Gigs and it started working.

```
resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 300m
        memory: 128Mi
```

Changed to:

```
resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 300m
        memory: 1Gi
```

Answer (score -11):

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --shm-size 2G --name chrome chrome-hd
```

to run container locally where

```
--shm-size 2G
```

is used to tweak shm available size.

Comment: Please re-read the question. I already use --shm-size to run locally. This is a question about kubectl configuration