# How to Change the Size of /dev/shm in App Engine Flexible

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, shared-memory, app-engine-flexible

How do you change the size of the shared memory folder `/dev/shm` in an App Engine Flexible app?

By default it is set to 64M, too low to run many apps (e.g., chrome).  I don't see any way to change it. There are ways to change it if you have access to the [docker run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30210362/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-dev-shm-in-docker-container), but we don't have such access when launching app engine flexible apps.

Comment: You should query google support also for this. The documentation around customization is not available much

Comment: So it's not the same thing but you can create tmpfs volumes if that helps.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings

Comment: @ZachFewtrell that would help if you were able to mount to /dev/shm. I tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A: No.**

Unfortunately this isn't possible (yet?) with appengine. More than a few people have run into this issue. For some reason, the container default for /dev/shm is crazy small.

**...but there are other options**

If the process you want to run has the ability to configure the location of the tmpfs it uses, then you can [create a tmpfs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) and simply point it there. **Chromium can't do this.**

**Option 1**

If you want to deploy a container to google cloud, one option is to use [container engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/). You can then mount a tmpfs volume to your pods like this:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: dshm
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/project/image
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /dev/shm
        name: dshm
```

Kubernetes has a fairly steep learning curve, but it will allow you to uncap the limit on /dev/shm.

**Option 2**

There is a new feature that will allow you to [deploy containers to compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers), but it's currently in alpha and you will need to apply to have your project whitelisted to use this feature.

**Option 3**

Of course, you could deploy containers to GCE in a more manual fashion by creating a GCE instance using [COS (container optimized os)](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/)

---

Update from speedplane's comment

**Option #4**

If the goal is to run a full browser on app engine flexible, then the new versions of Firefox run in headless just fine in Docker.

Comment: I would add option #4 (which is what I went with)... if the goal is to run a full browser on app engine flexible, then the new versions of Firefox run in headless just fine in Docker.

Comment: I will also add, that after upgrading to a newer version of Firefox, I started running into this issue. Maybe the newer versions use more shared memory? The versions that work for me are Firefox 56.0.2 and Geckodriver v0.19.1.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer I received from Google Support (support ID 13757624):

> I understand that you have inquiry if it would be possible to increase
>   the size of /dev/shm in App Engine Flex.
>
> Unfortunately, this isn't possible. Since Flex is managed VM the
>   default value is maintained. You may try to create manually a command
>   on your dockerfile to change the shared cache via 'sudo' but there's
>   no guarantee so I can't say that it will possibly work, still worth a
>   try given that you are using custom runtimes otherwise, there's no
>   other way.