# Troubleshooting onyx-kafka not writing to a topic. Howto run kafka in docker swarm. Error setting runtime volume size (/dev/shm)?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, docker-swarm, stream-processing

I'm trying to **i)** troubleshoot a simple [onyx-kafka](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-kafka) job not writing to a topic. More details are given [here](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-kafka/issues/47). And you can try it out in this [sample project](https://github.com/twashing/simple-kafka-onyx-commander/tree/cloud-orchestration-2). I think the reason is because there's only one kafka node.

So I tried **ii)** launching kafka `confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.3.1` (with zookeeper `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:3.3.1`) running docker (17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4) ***in swarm mode***. But then I get this error.

```
Warning: space is running low in /dev/shm (shm) threshold=167,772,160 usable=58,716,160
```

**A)** With docker compose, I could just configure the mounted `/dev/shm` disk to have more capacity with the configuration option `shm_size: 1G` (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)).

Is there an equivalent for docker swarm? I just need to control the size of the disk volume. But I don’t see such an option in docker compose’s `deploy` configuration (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy)). And the `docker service --mount` [option](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26714) doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any options here?

**B)** I don't quite grok the `Memory` volume mount [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085748/define-size-for-dev-shm-on-container-engine). So don't know if that's a workable option.

**C)** Thanks to Andrew Mulholland (@itwasntandy) from the `devops-engineers` Slack channel, I can fake it by passing in `--mount type=tmpfs,dst=/dev/shm,tmpfs-size=768000000` as options to a call to `docker service create ...` (see [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26714)).

But the offical documentation says that the *tmpfs* option is [not supported](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#not-supported-for-docker-stack-deploy) for `docker stack deploy`. This optiononly applies to docker compose's [service configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference). It doesn't apply to docker's swarm mode.

**Summary**. So is there any way to get that option into my existing *docker-compose.yml* file, in the swarm configuration?

I’d love to be able to run `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml my-app`. Details are [here](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-kafka/issues/47). Sample project is [here](https://github.com/twashing/simple-kafka-onyx-commander/tree/cloud-orchestration-2). Ultimately, I want to:

- **i)** run a docker stack, with a service which has onyx-kafka write to a topic (see [here](https://github.com/onyx-platform/onyx-kafka/issues/47)). And for that, I think I need to...
- **ii)** launch docker (17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4) in swarm mode, with the images kafka `confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.3.1` (with zookeeper
  `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:3.3.1`). But I'm running into this memory error issue.